# TADOConnection check for incorrect Credentials

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7

I am using the following connection string:

```pascal
ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};' +
                                   'Server=db4free.net;Port=3306;' +
                                   'Database=inventmanager;' +
                                   'User=' + eUser.text + ';Password=' + ePass.Text +
                                   ';Option=3;';
```

eUser, and ePass being TEdits on the main form.

When executing:

```
ADOConnection1.Connected := true;
```

Is their a way to test if the credentials are incorrect and then showing a MessageDlg?

Comment: You should always **add** the generic [tag:delphi] tag to your delphi related questions to have the correct syntax highlighter and more attention on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the credentials are invalid The MySQL Server returns a error [`1044 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dbaccess_denied_error). Unfortunately the MySQL ODBC Driver doesn't retrieve a specific error code when the credentials are invalid instead return a generic `80004005` error code . So you best option is parse the message string and search for  the `Access denied for user` string.

```
try
   ...
   ...   
   ADOConnection1.Connected:=True;
except
   on e:  EOleException do
   begin
     if Pos('Access denied for user', e.Message)>0 then
       ShowMessage('Invalid Credentials')
     else
       ShowMessage(Format('ErrorCode %x Message %s Source %s',[e.ErrorCode, e.Message, e.source]));
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Had to add the comobj unit to uses, but works perfectly